# Download .txt file and extract file name

Tags: python, pandas, download, python-requests

I am trying to download the file in Python from the url https://marketdata.theocc.com/position-limits?reportType=change.

I am able to convert it to DataFrame just by using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://marketdata.theocc.com/position-limits?reportType=change')
```

But what I want is to obtain the name of the file also.
so, if you download the file directly from browser the name of the file obtain is "POSITIONLIMITCHANGE_20201202.txt".

Can someone suggest an efficient way to do this in Python?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the `requests` library, the information about the file is in the response header (a dictionary):

```py
response = requests.get('https://marketdata.theocc.com/position-limits?reportType=change')
print(response.headers['content-disposition'])
```

Output:

```py
attachment; filename=POSITIONLIMITCHANGE_20201202.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Example code in Python to fetch a file from URL, extract filename, save to local file, and import into Pandas dataframe.

```python
import io
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://marketdata.theocc.com/position-limits?reportType=change'
r = requests.get(url)
# NOTE: filename is found in content-disposition HTTP response header
s = r.headers.get('content-disposition')

# use regexp with \w to match only safe characters in filename
# this will prevent accepting paths or drive letters as part of name
m = re.search(r'filename=(\w+)', s)
if m:
    filename = m.group(1)
else:
    # set default if filename not provided or name has bad characters
    filename = "out.csv"
print("filename:", filename)
text = r.text

# if you want to write out file with filename provided
with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(text)

# to read from string in-memory wrap with io.StringIO()
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text))
print(list(df.columns))
```

Output:

```
filename: POSITIONLIMITCHANGE_20201202.txt
['Equity_Symbol','   ','Start_Date','Start_Pos_Limit','End_Date','End_Pos_Limit','Action']
```